# External log4j configuration file not loaded from executable jar

Tags: java, log4j2

I need to import my log4j2 configuration file at runtime once the user gives a parameter pointing to the path where the configuration file is located (I cannot use the -Dlog4j.configurationFile parameter).

All works fine when the code is executed inside Eclipse IDE, the configuration is correctly loaded from the external file, passed as parameter by the user.
Once i build the jar file, the same piece of code does not work and configuration of the external file is not correctly loaded for my logs.

The path to the log file is given as absolute path.

Log4j2 version: 2.11

Here is the code that i'm currently using:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
                    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
                    File file = new File(args[0]);
                    context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
                    .....................
        }
```

args[0] contains the absolute path to the log4j2 configuration file.

Any idea of what i am doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
LoggerContext context = Configurator.initialize("MyApp", null, file.toURI());
```

or just

```
loggerContext context = Configurator.iniitalize("MyApp", null, args[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading a properties file or XML file. I had issues with properties file, but the XML one worked fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add detailed information, what kind of jar you are using. whether this is a spring boot application ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30595058)